# Query is executed on each page of a form although the result is stored in a session

Tags: php, laravel, session, eloquent

I'm creating a list of questions (multiple forms) and I set up a progress bar that shows the number of questions until the last one. I want to keep the max(id) of my table until the last form, and **I would like to avoid executing the same query fetching the max id on each page load**.

The query should be fired only if the result does not exist in a session variable.
In the constructor of my controller, I tell Laravel to store a session with the max id of the query only if the session does not yet exist, like so:

```
public function __construct() 
{
    if (! session()->has('maxid'))
        session(['maxid' => Question::max('id')]);  
}
```

However, when I look at Laravel's Telescope, it shows that the query is executed on each page :

```
select max(`id`) as aggregate from `questions`
```

Why is the query executed on each page although the session (maxid) exists ?    Is there a workaround ?

Comment: you dont have access to the session in the constructor of the controller like that, the request has not gone through the middleware stack yet, which is what creates the session

Comment: why do you need the max id? seems very sub optimal, compared to there can be created question after the code has been running.

Comment: @lagbox ok, so I'm wrong when trying to create the session in the controller...

Comment: @mrhn I need the max id ony to show to the user the total number of questions.

Comment: you can check that in the constructor if you really wanted to but you would have to use a middleware to do it

Comment: Ok so the session MUST be written in a middleware. Is this correct ?

Comment: if you wanted to do something in the constructor of the controller, yes, otherwise you are fine to access the session in any method of the controller that a route is pointing to